# laravel social login for multiple user session getting lost on callback url

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8

```
public function SocialRedirectEmployer($provider)
{
    session()->set('role_id',  request()->segment(3));
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}
public function SocialRedirectEmp($provider)
{
    session()->put('role_id',  request()->segment(3));
    session(['my_variable' => "lll"]);
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}
```

**Routes are**

```
Route::get('loginEmployer/{provider}/rec', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'SocialRedirectEmployer']);
Route::get('loginEmp/{provider}/emp', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'SocialRedirectEmp']);
Route::get('login/{provider}/callback',[App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'SocialCallback']);
```

**Afer call back url session is lost getting null**

```
 public function SocialCallback($provider){
        $userSocial =   Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
            
        $role = session()->get('role_id');
        var_dump("role = ".$role);
        dd(session('my_variable'));
        dd(\request()->segment(3));
}
```

**and request segment also not getting no callback url**

Answer (score 0):

For Session, You can use
use Session;

where library define
And for callback url you can [this](https://sinkcup.github.io/laravel-socialite-multiple-providers)

Comment: Im trying to use session, but when callback from login im getting null values from session stored value